# How to manage state of many dynamic variables without manually setting each and every variable on my own

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I'm new to react, I have 1000+ dynamically created input fields. How do I manage input values without setting the initial state on my own. The input element is generated in ToggleSwitch Component. Do you have any tips on how I could set all of the values dynamically?

```
  const displayConsentInfo = () => {
    return (
      <ul>
        <h3>Purposes</h3>
        {Object.keys(data.purposes).map((keyName) => (
          <li key={data.purposes[keyName].id}>
              <h5>{data.purposes[keyName].name}</h5>
              <p>{data.purposes[keyName].description}</p>
              <div class={style.consent_box}>
                  <span class={style.toggle_option}>Consent</span>
                  <ToggleSwitch checked={false} name={'purposesConsent'} onClick={sendData} dataID={data.purposes[keyName].id} />
              </div>

              {data.purposes[keyName].id != 1 &&
                <div class={style.consent_box}>
                    <span class={style.toggle_option}>Legitimate interest</span>
                    <ToggleSwitch checked={true} name={'purposesLegitimate[]'} />
                </div>
              }
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

This is just a snippet of my code, I have a few more dynamically generated inputs for other options too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Add a `useState` in your fucntion component.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const [data, setData] = useState(data.purposes);

onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        setData((data) =>  Object.assign(data, e.target.name, e.target.value))
```

change your sendData function to send the `data` object

```
sendData = () => {
  // callApi(<url>, data);
}
```

In your input fields add an `onChange` callback.

```
<ToggleSwitch  
    onChange={onChangeHandler} 
    name={keyName}
    onClick={sendData}/>
```